# Return value on MouseClick

Tags: java, jlist, listselectionlistener

I have a method in my program that will be executed if I click a certain area. That method will show a new JFrame with a JList inside. I want the method to return the name of the Item selected when I click it. However, the compiler does not allow me to do it. It gives me *error: incompatible types: unexpected return value*. Here is my code:

```
public static String listMethod(){
    //does stuff
    jlist.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
            if (!event.getValueIsAdjusting()){
                int output = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure?","Warning",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if(output == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                try{
                    frameList.dispose();
                    //this here
                    return jlist.getSelectedValue().toString();
                    //this here

                    }catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }

                }else if(output == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){

                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please give more information as to where the compiler give error

Comment: how can you return anything from a void method.you cannot return.i don't know why do you want to return a value

Comment: Look Here. This will probably give you a better idea of how to handle this. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html

Comment: I updated it with more info

Comment: To elaborate on what Fast Snail said. You cannot return a value from the selection listener because obviously the signature is a void method and two the code that calls it is handled by the swing/awt code. The best you can do is either pass your object to another method or save the value in a member variable to be used at another time(think carefully about synchronization here).

Comment: Thanks, you are totally right